# Winforms Layout: Expand/Collapse parts of UI

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

First thing: it's not possible to use WPF, because it's a plugin (for SolidWorks) and a ElementHost for WPF results in display-errors.

I need to make the ui elements relative. That means, that if I hide some elements i want the elements below to close the gap.

I tried with anchors and a growandshrink/autosize panel - no luck.

Example UI:

```
[Button]
[*] Checked RadioButton
       [TextField]
       [AnotherTextField]
[ ] Unchecked RadioButton
[Button]
```

After changing the selected RadioButton the second RadioButton and all following elements should close the gap and look like this:

```
[Button]
[ ] Unchecked RadioButton
[*] Checked RadioButton
[Button]
```

Comment: This may not apply...how about using a `Tree View`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is trivial to do with a FlowLayoutPanel.  Set the Flow property to TopDown.  Add a RadioButton, two TextBoxes and another RadioButton.  Set the Margin property on the TextBoxes so they look indented (Left = 20 for example), their Visible property to False.

Then you just need to tiny sliver of code to make their Visible property follow the radio button's Checked property:

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        textBox1.Visible = textBox2.Visible = radioButton1.Checked;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to put as many panels and set Dock to Top value. In each panel goes one of the controls. I tried simple test - make event on click to panel - to hide it. All panels below will go up